# Manipulating files Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Folks,

I have a difficulty here to manipulate files.

Objective: I'm developing a script that needs to create folders and copy files from a source, the script reads the user the number of months to create. The script replicates the files equal the number of months to be created, if in 2017 need to change a string to a .txt file into the directory.

original string within the file: ANO INICIO DO ESTUDO 2016
String is to be changed: ANO INICIO DO ESTUDO 2017

PS: The file to be changed is not the original but a copy

**It is possible to change a line from a txt file?**

What I need:

Read program source file and play to an array
identifying a portion of a string within the array
modify the string if it is found to be part of the string
delete the source file and write another with the same name, or simply change a string (a word in a row) within the source file.

```
FILENAME_NEWAVE = Path of the source file
STRING_DGER = String to be searched
FILE_DATE = Year
```

This is not working, you are writing in the source file

```
def find_word_in_file_dger(FILENAME_NEWAVE, STRING_DGER, FILE_DATE):
   f = open(FILENAME_NEWAVE, "r+")
   file_array = f.readlines()
   for i in file_array:
       if i.find(STRING_DGER.encode('utf-8')):
           f.write(i)
       else:
           print ("TO LENDO O ARRAY")
           if FILE_DATE == "2016":
               continue
           else:
               i.replace(STRING_DGER, "ANO INICIO DO ESTUDO " + FILE_DATE)
               f.write(i)
               print("TO ESCREVENDO A LINHA CORRETAMENTE MLK!! ")
           return i
   f.close()
   return False
```

Comment: You can try with somenthig like this:

`import re`

`cache = None`
`with open("file.txt", "r") as f:`
 `cache = f.read()`

`new_file = re.sub(STRING_DGER, "ANO INICIO DO ESTUDO {}".format(FILE_DATE), cache)`

`if new_file:`
 `with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f:`
  `f.write(new_file)`

Comment: Works! But the string that existed in the file was still there, I need to delete the string "2016" which is on file and put "2017" in place. If 2017 put 2018...

Comment: has the accent on the file appears this error message, "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 1355: ordinal not in range(128) "

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this will work. Regarding the UnicodeDecodeError ill suggest you give a look at [this](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

```
import re
cache = None
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
     cache = f.read()
new_file = re.sub("2017", "2018", cache) 
new_file = re.sub("2016", "2017", new_file)
if new_file: 
    with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f: 
        f.write(new_file)
```